# What package contains org/eclipse/ocl/helper/OCLSyntaxHelper?

Tags: java, eclipse

What package do I need to install in Eclipse to resolve org/eclipse/ocl/helper/OCLSyntaxHelper? I can't find the OCLSyntaxHelper class in an Eclipse repo.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ocl/helper/OCLSyntaxHelper
>       at org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.OCL.newInstance(OCL.java:127)
>       at RefOntoUML.impl.ElementImpl.(ElementImpl.java:581)
>       at RefOntoUML.impl.RefOntoUMLFactoryImpl.createPackage(RefOntoUMLFactoryImpl.java:278)
>       at RefOntoUML.util.RefOntoUMLFactoryUtil.createPackage(RefOntoUMLFactoryUtil.java:55)
>       at myPackage.MyFirstProgrammaticOntoUMLDiagram.CreateOntoUMLDiagram(MyFirstProgrammaticOntoUMLDiagram.java:40)
>       at myPackage.MyFirstProgrammaticOntoUMLDiagram.main(MyFirstProgrammaticOntoUMLDiagram.java:32)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ocl.helper.OCLSyntaxHelper
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 6 more

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the IDE??

Comment: Yes.  Here are more characters so this response will be accepted.

Comment: Seems like a corrupt installation. This was a bug long ago. Did you try re-installing Eclipse?

Comment: Do you have a link? How do you know it was a bug? Eclipse doesn't "install" as such, it just unzips into a folder and executes from a binary. There is no installation process.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413749 and eclipse does have an installer version

Comment: Also, check this out- http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html and do upload your code. Only the error is not helping.

Comment: That link doesn't help (I have been reading it for hours) because I need to know where org/eclipse/ocl/helper/OCLSyntaxHelper comes from so I can install the package from a repo. The code is not relevant because it's a run-time error originating in a in a jar file, as indicated in the original question.

Comment: then there might be some problem with the external libraries, if any

Comment: Not helping. Where is OCLSyntaxHelper ? What repo?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Eclipse Modeling tools. All is well.